# How to delete an HBase cell with a binary rowkey through REST api?

Tags: rest, hbase

The path to delete an HBase cell through REST api is `/<table>/<row>/<column>:<qualifier>`.  If the rowkey is a string, like "Hello", it works. But when the rowkey is binary data (for example, an integer of 180) how should I encode the rowkey? I tried base64 encoding the rowkey and got a status code of 200, but that cell was not deleted at all.

Example:

I tried to delete a cell by sending a DELETE request to the path `http://ecs5.njzd.com:20550/X/ZAAAAA==/C:c1`, where `ecs5.njzd.com:20550` is the hostname and port of HBase REST server,  `X` is the name of the table, `ZAAAAA==` is the based64 decoded value of the rowkey `100` (int), and `C:c1` is the column name. I got a response with a status code of 200 but the cell still exists in the table.

Comment: Can you paste smaple scan output of your hbase table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is to write the `rowkey` in the form of **hex-escaped representation of the corresponding byte array**.  For example, when the rowkey is an integer of 100, I should write the rowkey as `d\x00\x00\x00`, which is the hex-escaped representation of the integer `100`.

Actually when you scan a table in HBase shell, you will see the same result if a `rowkey` or `value` is not a string.

Answer (score 2):

I simply tried below command and it worked for me. You dont to send base64 encoded data in delete query.

curl -v -X DELETE  "Content-Type: text/xml"   http://hostname:port/testtable/10101/colfam1:col1

If it does not works then paste hbase scan output of your table which will give idea about preparing delete query.

Comment: You must place "-H" before "Content-Type..."

Answer (score 0):

The delete is not straight forward just like put or get. It depends on major compaction, version based, timestamp based, autoflush etc. So when you say that you are seeing it back, please verify these settings as well. As @Shashi said, the schema itself is defined for delete in Rest API, to handle it with encoding, So you need not send encoded data